# What is this conflict when merging Git branches in VS2013?

Tags: git, visual-studio-2013

I'm doing a merge between two branches and I have a bunch of these conflicts:

> Branches have a file with the same name.
>
> Renamed to FILE on SOURCE
>
> Added FILE to TARGET

My options are either Take on SOURCE or Keep on TARGET, but both of them demand I rename the file to something else. Why is it forcing me to rename it? Is there a way to just Take/Keep without changing the file name? The files are identical so it doesn't matter which version I keep as long as it's not renamed.

Comment: Might not be the answer you're looking for, but i recommend using git from commandline. It's extremely well documented and will work for your vs projects and everywhere else you need git.